# selecting individual items in an unordered list using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to sort through a list of items parsed by beautiful soup. Each item has a unique link and text but I can't figure out how to select an individual item, besides the first in the list.

```
#Finds all div's with class image_list
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})

#selects the ul with the links I want to sort through
RHAZ = containers[1]
```

Here are some of the things I've tried with no luck:

```
#200 is one of the unique numbers a li has.
RHAZ.li.findAll("a", {"href":"200"})

RHAZ.li.findAll("a", {"text":"200"})
```

This is what the HTML from the page looks like

```
<div class="image_list">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="./?s=2127&camera=RHAZ%5F">Sol 2127 (4 img)</a></li>
   <li><a href="./?s=2126&camera=RHAZ%5F">Sol 2126 (4 img)</a></li>
    ....
```

This goes on from 2127 - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Find the division, then find the list items within the division. For each item, get its "a" tag and the tag's attributes.

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''<div class="image_list">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="./?s=2127&camera=RHAZ%5F">Sol 2127 (4 img)</a></li>
    <li><a href="./?s=2126&camera=RHAZ%5F">Sol 2126 (4 img)</a></li>''')

for li in soup.find("div", {"class": "image_list"}).findAll('li'):
   print(li.a.text, li.a['href'])
#Sol 2127 (4 img) ./?s=2127&camera=RHAZ%5F
#Sol 2126 (4 img) ./?s=2126&camera=RHAZ%5F
```

Comment: This is not possible, because `li` is a loop variable. I tested my code once again, and it works. Just in case, I included a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Neither your href text, nor your href equals to 200, try with this

```
import re

RHAZ.li.find_all("a", href=re.compile("RHAZ"))
RHAZ.li.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and "RHAZ" in href)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this just prints the first list item

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector 'div.image_list a', this will find all `<a>`tags inside `<div>` tags with class `image_list`:

```
data = """
<div class="image_list">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="./?s=2127&camera=RHAZ%5F">Sol 2127 (4 img)</a></li>
   <li><a href="./?s=2126&camera=RHAZ%5F">Sol 2126 (4 img)</a></li>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('div.image_list a'):
    print(a.text, a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
Sol 2127 (4 img) ./?s=2127&camera=RHAZ%5F
Sol 2126 (4 img) ./?s=2126&camera=RHAZ%5F
```